# Is it correct to use "a lot of amount"

Tags: quantifiers

Is the term " a lot of amount " correct? Since ," a lot of "implies a quantity,  "a lot of amount " is hardly in use.

Comment: you could have " a *large* amount of.." or "a large quantity of..."

Answer (score 1):

As you already understand, **amount** and **quantity** have largely overlapping, almost identical, fields of meaning. Neither, however, implies anything about relative size. An amount may be relatively large or small. A **lot** means a large quantity or amount so **a lot of amount** is redundant and not at all idiomatic.